# ZXing.net.mobile scan in landscape orientation

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, zxing

I have used the Zxing.Net.Mobile Nuget package... I have made Auto-rotate=false, so that it can scan vertical barcodes. The problem is because it starts scanning in portrait theres no way no scan in landscape and also have orientation locked. I want an option to scan locked in landscape. Here is my code:

```
               Button scanbutton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ScanButton);
        scanbutton.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {                
                var result = await _scanner.Scan(new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
                {
                    AutoRotate = false,                   
                });
                if (result != null)
                {                   
                    await CallService();
                }
        };
```

Comment: does anyone know how to find the CameraConfiguration class??

Answer (score 2):

Check if `TryHarder = true` inside `MobileBarcodeScanningOptions` works for you. If activated, the code will be rotated three times and checked from all 90° angles.

Comment: Just to add, `TryHarder` is obsolete now - so use `barcodeReader.Options.TryHarder` instead